# How to make Shopping Cart Rule work with Configurable Product in Magento?

Tags: product, custom, shopping-cart, configurable-product, rules

Shopping Cart Rule in Magento doesn't allow the condition custom attribute of product . I want to make rule with condition size 8 , men. I found some solutions on Internet but they don't work.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your custom attribute available for the rules.
Go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes, edit your attribute and set the field `Used for promo rules` to `yes`. Reindex everything and your are done.

Comment: this does not solve the question in the particular case of a "configurable product". Also in M1938 we have seen: if an attibute is set on the configurable/parent level only ... the shopping cart price rule does not work (it validates against the simple product) ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219885/magento-1-x-shopping-cart-rules-apply-discount-action-not-working-for-parent-co